# Change the text content of the page margin (top right and bottom right) in browser page print

Tags: html, css, printing

The requirement is to change the text content of the page margin (top right and bottom right)

Modifying margin content with @page properties doesn't apply.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-kate-i2hdxw?file=/index.css

Click on print button in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-kate-i2hdxw?file=/index.css) to see the print preview

CSS:

```css
@page {
  margin: 50px;

  @top-right {
    content: "My custom content";
    background-color: red;
  }

  @bottom-right {
    content: "MY PAGE COUNT";
  }
}
```

Comment: No, the page doesn't have control over that. See [Paged media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media).

Comment: It should tho, according to the [spec](https://www.quackit.com/css/at-rules/css_bottom-right-corner_at-rule.cfm#:~:text=The%20%40bottom%2Dright%2Dcorner,boxes%20inside%20the%20page%20context.),

Comment: That's not a required module. None of the new at-rules it adds aren't even listed in [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20at-rule). You can, of course, submit requests for implementation to the various browser bug trackers. The likelihood of being implemented soon or at all is pretty low though. Even the page you link to notes that this spec is experimental and could be dropped or changed.